# How to find closest object without costing too much?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have searched the net and best possible way I found is this:

```
Transform GetClosestEnemy(Transform[] objects)
{
    Transform BestTarget = null;
    float ClosestDistance = float.MaxValue;
    Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;

    foreach (Transform CurrentObject in objects)
    {
        Vector3 DifferenceToTarget = CurrentObject.position - currentPosition;
        float DistanceToTarget = DifferenceToTarget.sqrMagnitude;

        if (DistanceToTarget < ClosestDistance)
        {
            ClosestDistance = DistanceToTarget;
            BestTarget = CurrentObject;
        }
    }

    return BestTarget;
}
```

This seems the best way but my real question is, can I use `Physics.SphereCast` , `OnCollisionStay` or something to feed this function? I feel like they will be more expensive than just going through all of the possible objects. Is it true? How do these functions *actually* work?

Comment: I guess this depends a lot on how many objects there are .. do you know them all beforehand? Probably comes down to debug/profile it in your specific use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is indeed very well written and optimized. However using `Physics.SphereCast` and `OnCollisionStay` to feed it would be nonsensical.

[`Physics.SphereCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) is essentially a "thick" and more expensive raycast. It can tell you if an object with a collider is on its path, with a bit more detailed information about the first collider that was hit. Obviously finding the closest object if you only have one undermines needing an algorithm. If your underlying problem was to find the closest object in a particular direction it could solve it on its own.

There is a related function called [`Physics.SphereCastAll`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCastAll.html), which could make a bit more sense, since that one returns all objects in the path of the cast, but your question would have to be something along the line of "which object is closest to this unrelated point among all the objects in front this other point".

[`OnCollisionStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay.html) is individually called every physics timestep for every object with a collider and rigidbody that is in contact with the collider. It's no good for area selection, since it will actively push out all objects inside. You might have meant [`OnTriggerStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html), which does work for an area, but is still not fitting for the problem. The nature of this method would require a bunch of memory to save what objects are in and a chunk of processing power since all that would be done every physics time step (0.03s by default), which is why I wouldn't even consider it. Personally I don't think it is even possible to solve your problem with `OnCollisionStay`, I would use a combination of `OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionExit` if someone insisted on using triggers.

In my opinion the function that makes most sense is [`Physics.OverlapSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html). It returns an array of colliders within a specified radius. It could basically perform a physics based "prefiltering" so objects at the other end of the scene aren't even considered.

The following code shows an example on how you could use `Physics.OverlapSphere` to get a set of objects, convert them to transforms, pass them to your function and print the result.

```csharp
Collider[] hitCollider = Physics.Overlaobjsphere(center, radius);
Transform[] objs = new Transform[hitCollider.Length];
for(int i=0; i<hitCollider.Length; i++){
  objs[i] = hitCollider[i].transform;
}
Debug.Log(GetClosestEnemy(objs));
```

A small quirk is that `Physics.OverlapSphere` returns the Colliders and any given GameObject can have multiples of those. That means that we might be calculating the same object several times. In this case it is acceptable, since filtering them out will take more processing power than just running them thru another time.

The people that made the physics engine worked hard to optimize it. Nevertheless it can be expensive to involve physics. For example if you are going to check the same five objects over and over again doing a sphere overlap might not make sense. On the other hand if the objects of interest are instantiated and deleted all the time it might be unavoidable to use Physics to even gather a set to check against. For the average user these optimization considerations are unnecessary. Modern hardware usually has enough computational power. Never the less if you are curious you can always program a benchmark, repeating the algorithm a million times and measuring the time that it took using a [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-7.0).

Comment: `OnCollisionStay is individually called every physics timestep for every object with a collider and rigidbody that remain within a trigger` .. nope, that would be `OnTriggerStay` ;) there are no real collisions if your object is a trigger

Comment: @derHugo I am dumb. My brain substituted `OnCollisionStay` with `OnTriggerStay`. Terrible mistake that I have to correct.